# How to parse this type of link in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to parse the following link:- 
        http://www.cbapcertprep.com/service/index.php?/Download_vehicletrack/DownloadTrackData/35170

how to  show longitude and latitude data in table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume that this is your .m file

```
@interface searchResultsViewController ()
{
NSMutableArray *getlot, *getlong;
 }
 @end
```

in your view did load

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
getlong =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
getlot =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[self getdails];     //this get the longitude and latitude fr
}

-(void) getdails
{
   NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.cbapcertprep.com/service/index.php?/Download_vehicletrack/DownloadTrackData/35170"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

for (int i=0; i<[jsonArray count]; i++)
{
    NSString *strlong=[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"longitude"];
     NSString *strlat=[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"latitude"];

   [getlong addObject: strlong];
   [getlot addObject: strlat];

}
[self.yourtableview reloaddata];
}


 #pragma mark - tablevie data source

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

 return [getlong count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;


}
 cell.textlabel.text=[getlot objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.detailTextLabel.text=[getlong objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;

  }
```

Comment: customize your self in tableview

Comment: in that application crash it

Comment: can u show the crash report

Comment: [getlong addObject: strlong];
   [getlot addObject: strlat]; crash in that line

Comment: just hold on , i try for my self

Comment: here is your project available, download at this link http://www.sendspace.com/file/p123ba

Comment: run and show the answer, if u got the result in table give the marks on this question

Answer (score 0):

Just using JSON Parsing do following:

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in dataArray)
{
    NSLog(@"latitude %@",[dict objectForKey:@"latitude"]);
    NSLog(@"longitude %@",[dict objectForKey:@"longitude"]);
}
```